# SQLite Not Saving JSON Token

Tags: android, json, sqlite, exception

I have a DBHelper class and I have saved info from user. I also want to save the user's token from server but errors are showing in logcat. Please look at my code and point out my mistake.

My DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tingUser.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "profileInfo";
private static final String IMAGES_TABLE = "userImage";

private static final String COL_ID = "databaseId";
public static final String COL_USER_ID = "userId";
public static final String COL_FULL_NAME = "fullName";
public static final String COL_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String COL_DOB = "DOB";
public static final String COL_MOBILE_NUM = "mobileNum";
public static final String COL_OCCUPATION = "occupation";
public static final String COL_ORGANIZATION = "organization";
public static final String COL_TOKEN = "JWT Token";

private static final String COL_PROFILE_PHOTO = "profilePhoto";

private Context mCtx;

private DatabaseManager databaseManager;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBHelper(Context context){
    this.mCtx = context;
    databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(mCtx);
}

public DBHelper open() throws SQLException{
    db = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    databaseManager.close();
}

public boolean saveInputField(TingTingUser user){
    SQLiteDatabase userDb = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_FULL_NAME, user.getDisplayName());
    values.put(COL_USER_ID, user.getUserId());
    values.put(COL_GENDER, user.getGender());
    values.put(COL_DOB, user.getDob());
    values.put(COL_MOBILE_NUM, user.getMobileNumber());
    values.put(COL_ORGANIZATION, user.getOrganization());
    values.put(COL_OCCUPATION, user.getOccupation());
    values.put(COL_TOKEN, user.getJWT_token());
    Log.d("database",values.toString());
    //values.put(COL_TOKEN, (user.getJWT_token() != null) ? user.getJWT_token() : null);

    long result = userDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); // error occurs here 
    userDb.close();

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

public TingTingUser getCurrentUser(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase currDB = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = currDB.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_ID, COL_USER_ID, COL_FULL_NAME, COL_GENDER, COL_DOB, COL_MOBILE_NUM, COL_OCCUPATION, COL_ORGANIZATION}, COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        TingTingUser user = new TingTingUser(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7) );
        return user;
    }

    return null;

}

public void saveCameraImage(byte[] imageBytes){
    SQLiteDatabase camDb = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_PROFILE_PHOTO, imageBytes);
    camDb.insert(IMAGES_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public void saveGalleryImage(byte[] imageBytes){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_PROFILE_PHOTO, imageBytes);
    db.insert(IMAGES_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public byte[] getImage(){
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, IMAGES_TABLE, new String[]{COL_PROFILE_PHOTO,}, null, null, null, null, COL_ID + " DESC", "1");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PROFILE_PHOTO));
        cursor.close();
        return blob;
    }
    cursor.close();
    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "No Image Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String db_create = " Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COL_USER_ID + " TEXT, "
                + COL_FULL_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + COL_GENDER + " TEXT, "
                + COL_DOB + " TEXT, "
                + COL_MOBILE_NUM + " TEXT, "
                + COL_OCCUPATION + " TEXT, "
                + COL_ORGANIZATION + " TEXT "
                + COL_TOKEN + " TEXT VARCHAR 1024) ";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(db_create);

        String img_create = "Create table " + IMAGES_TABLE + " ("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COL_PROFILE_PHOTO + " BLOB NOT NULL )";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(img_create);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + IMAGES_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

}

}
```

In my activity, other fields are saving except the token. I have called helper method to save token like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest otpObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.TING_VERIFY_OTP_ENDPOINT, verifyOTPObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("OTPDialogFragment", "OTP Verification Response is: \t" + response.toString());
                Log.d("OTPDialogFragment", "OTP Verified Successfully");

                try {
                    JSONObject verifyObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONObject userObject = verifyObject.getJSONObject("user");

                    userId = userObject.getString("_id");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved user id is:\t" + userId);

                    userToken = verifyObject.getString("token");  // getting user token from server correctly
                    Log.d("jwt token", userToken);

                    TingTingUser user = new TingTingUser();
                    user.setDisplayName(fullName);
                    user.setMobileNumber(num);
                    user.setGender(genderVal);
                    user.setDob(dob);
                    user.setOccupation("default");
                    user.setOrganization("default");
                    user.setUserId(userId);
                    user.setJWT_token(userToken);  // saving in model class

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(genderVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(dob) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userId) && !userToken.isEmpty()){

                        if (dbHelper.saveInputField(user) == true){  // saving model object in db and error occurs here
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

Error in logcat:

```
Error inserting JWT Token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1YTA5YTM3NDJhODE1YjIyNzhkMzBmYWUiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTA1ODExMTh9.0SpOuVkxAKQew539dif2Gjd2DRKgiR-A0IpU9mgs_zA fullName=the link userId=5a09a3742a815b2278d30fae occupation=default gender=Male DOB=1578335820 mobileNum=1234566789 organization=default
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Token": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO profileInfo(JWT Token,fullName,userId,occupation,gender,DOB,mobileNum,organization) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                           at com.billionusers.tingting.db.DBHelper.saveInputField(DBHelper.java:71)
                                                                           at com.billionusers.tingting.activities.SignUpActivity$OTPDialogFragment$6.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:480)
                                                                           at com.billionusers.tingting.activities.SignUpActivity$OTPDialogFragment$6.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:452)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

It shows a syntax error in my create table statement, but everything seems fine by me. Please point out my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO profileInfo(JWT_token,fullName,userId,occupation,gender,DOB,mobileNum,organization) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You cannot have spaces in variables.

Comment: Where should I add " " In dbhelper class or signup?

Comment: @AnandRajput I changed my answer, try to remove the space from the Variable